# How can i insert 2d random numbers into a given 2d matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to insert random numbers into a given 2D matrix in MATLAB. For example 
if

```
A = [1 2 3; 
     4 5 6;
     7 8 9];
```

and if `B` is a matrix which is uniformly distributed matrix, then I want a new matrix merging this two matrices (`A` & `B`), like 
new matrix

```
C = [1   0.653  2   2.55   3;
     4   4.3    5   5.4    6;
     7   7.6    8   8.09   9]
```

How could I write MATLAB code for that?

Comment: See here: [Interleave matrices in MATLAB with reshape](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/interleave_matrices).

Answer (score 1):

If you've already got `B` and assuming that `A` is an `n`-by-`m` matrix and `B` is an `n`-by-`m-1` matrix:

```
[n,m] = size(A);
C = zeros(n,2*m-1);
C(:,1:2:end) = A;
C(:,2:2:end) = B;  % end-1 is not necessary since 2*m-1 is an odd number but if you prefer for readability then you can do C(:,2:2:end-1) = B
```

You could create `B` like this (depends on the limits of `B` which are not clear from your question)

```
B = A(:,1:end-1) + rand(n,m-1)*2 - 1
```